# ::RegisterWIndowMessage() In Direct 2D application Compile Error

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, direct2d

I'm working on a Direct2D (XAML) application (I picked this because I haven't done it before and I wanted to try it out, I thought it would be simple).

I created the project in Visual Studio 2012 using the default options.

I added a button to the GUI successfully.

I added a button press handler to the GUI successfully.

The problem is that I need the button press handler to send a registered windows message. I `#include <Windows.h>` as instructed by the MSDN docs for `::RegisterWindowMessage()`, and finding the declaration and definition of the function with the F12 key works fine.

However, building the project fails, because the compiler can't find the function. Intellisense also flags the function as unrecognized.

I'm probably missing something in the project configuration, but I don't even know where to begin.

Can you please help me?

**Edit**: The exact error messages that I'm getting are:

```
 error C2039: 'RegisterWindowMessage' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
 error C3861: 'RegisterWindowMessage': identifier not found
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't make sense that you can navigate to the definition and still get a compile error message.  Do make sure it is not actually a link error message, you have to link user32.lib.   And do beware that you can't use it in a WinRT/UWP app, the somewhat likely scenario when you tinker with D2D and xaml.  Always, always copy paste the *exact* error message when you ask for help at SO.

Comment: I would be dumbfounded if a WinRT/UWP app was unable to send registered window messages, so if I can't link user32.lib (which it looks like I can't) how would I find the functions for registering and posting a message?

Comment: Feel free to be founded, a major design goal behind WinRT was to retire the 30 year old notion of a HWND.  User32 did not age well.  Using SendMessage is not sensible, nothing to send to.

Comment: That's fascinating. Is there any way to communicate between Win32 programs and WinRT/UWP apps?

Comment: That was another strong design goal, process interop is severely limited.  With a sandbox to enforce it. Keeps users happy to download apps from the store and not worry about them doing viral stuff.  Or run them on their phone without any protection.  The phone thingy didn't work out so well.

Answer (score 0):

[RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx) is not available in a UWP application (which is likely what you are targeting in a XAML application). If you look into *WinUser.h*, you'll find the declarations are wrapped inside a

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

guard. This API is available to desktop applications only. There is nothing you can do to make it work in a UWP application.